# Lost SF Story: Survival Training, Team abandoned due to Nova

Tags: story-identification, space

A group of Humans as part of their survival training are dropped on the surface of a planet. They are supposed to be picked up after a few weeks, this doesn't happen. They eventually discover that the reason is a Nova.

Comment: Some additional description notes:  http://www.dougturnbull.com/tunnel-sky/   Anything ring a bell?

Comment: Some various Tunnel in the Sky book covers if that helps jog a memory:  https://www.google.com/search?q=book+covers+for+tunnel+in+the+sky&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiln8Pt-K7RAhWmxlQKHW-dCOgQsAQIIg&biw=1342&bih=803

Comment: Thanks Beichst, it WAS Tunnel in the Sky by Heinlein. It was a Nova not a Super-Nova. I was actually asking on behalf of a friend, but I am fairly sure I read this a very long time ago. If you answer it I will mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for the offer. As it was simply a dup, no need for me to submit an answer. Just glad to hear this was it.  A great juvenile SF book that IMHO has held up well over the years.